# Pure Data windows:not supported, couldn't create

Tags: startup, setting, puredata

I am new to Pure Data and have no idea why the following are displayed after I clicked help:

[image]

I am using Windows 7 and pd-extended 0.43.4.

Comment: You might want to add the information which Pd version and flavor you are using and what operating system.

Comment: please don't post screenshots of error-messages; instead post text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [answer](http://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/topic/9689/puredata-midiin-windows-notsupported/2) on the pd forum by user whale-av already,

> whale-av:
>
> **[midiin] and [sysexin] are not supported in windows**. Some people have written patches to get around the lack of sysex, and instead of midiin you can use [ctrlin] [notein] etc.
>
> **[powtorms~] [mstopow~] do not exist as far as I know even in vanilla for windows, and in the windows extended 0.43.4 release they do not.** I remember seeing that they were in a Linux vanilla build, and in a very old Pd build for XP.... so you might be able to find them......... someone might have built them as an external that you could add to your pd/extra folder and then use them like any other object. If you have opened someone elses patch then it is possible that they used those objects in that patch, but you do not have them so they will not "create" and will just show the name in a red dotted box instead of a solid black outline.
>
> **[scalar] does not exist**, but [scalar-help] does and that explains how to use scalars....... which use other objects but not [scalar]
>   So, basically, **not all objects exist in all versions of Pd, and certainly not under all operating systems.**

Comment: Pd (vanilla) has a very stable object base (though there *are* a **handful** of objects that have changed in the last 20 years). For Pd-vanilla the statement `certainly not under all operating systems` is definitely wrong: some objects might not work at all or not as expected (e.g. `midiin`; but rumour has it that there are legacy error messages indcitating problems where there are none), but the set of available objects in Pd-vanilla is the same for all operating systems.

Comment: things are a little bit different with Pd-extended, as PdX includes a lot of libraries some of which are available only on certain OSs. however, the objects in the Q are none of them.

Answer (score 0):

This error (xy ...could not crate) means that this abstraction or external failed to instantiate. It could be that you don't have it installed, or it is not in Pd's search path so it can't find it. In the patch you are opening those objects seem to be used. In your case that might be the help file.